# Complements of torsion-free abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Here is my question: Let *A* be an abelian torsion-free group, and *B* be a subgroup of *A*. Can we always find another subgroup *C* of *A* such that *A/B* is isomorphic to *C*?

Answer (score 3):

No. Hint: Find an quotient with torsion.